# activar conda en visual code

Tags: python-3.x, visual

he intalado visual code por uqe me he visto en videos que es un editor muy versatil y pues no estoy muy familiarizado, tengo instalado python con conda y cada vez que entro en la terminal del visual me aparece esto:

```
   Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.18363.900]
   (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

   E:\Tareas>C:/Users/OOO.DESKTOP-8BMSU73/anaconda3/Scripts/activate

   (base) E:\Tareas>conda activate base

   (base) E:\Tareas>
```

No me parece que funcione de esta manera ya que aparecen unos errores de que no reconoce modulos instalados anteriormente, quisiera saber como arreglo esto cada vez que entro en la terminal del visual.

Answer (score 0):

Según este [tutorial](https://medium.com/@udiyosovzon/how-to-activate-conda-environment-in-vs-code-ce599497f20d), debes de añadir lo siguiente al `.json` de Visual Code.

```
“terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows”: [“/K”, “C:\\<path-to-conda-installation>\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\<path-to-conda-installation>”]
```

y cambiar `<path-to-conda-installation>` a la ruta donde tengas Anaconda3.